# Problemas con addRow para agregar filas de una tabla importada de base de datos mySQL - phpMyAdmin JAVA

Tags: java-swing

Simplemente no me reconoce la instrucción addRow ---- tablaDocentes.addRow(datos);

Cambio luego: tablaDocentes.addRowSelectionInterval(0,11); y me marca el siguiente error..

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Row index out of range

La verdad no bien como configurarlo.

-----------------------EL CÓDIGO ES EL SIGUIENTE ------------------------------------

```
    public void mostrarDatos(){
        
        String [] nombresColumnas={"ID DOCENTE","NOMBRE", "APELLIDOS","RFC","DIRECCIÓN","ESTADO CIVIL","TELEFONO","TELEFONO","EXPERIENCIA"+
            "TRABAJO ANTERIOR","CELULA", "ESPECIALIDAD","ULTIMO GRADO"};
        
        DefaultTableModel tablaDocente=new  DefaultTableModel(9,12);
        tablaDocentes.setModel(tablaDocente);
        tablaDocentes.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
        tablaDocentes.setCellSelectionEnabled(true);
        
        String [] datos =new String[12];
        
        try {
            
                Statement leer=conect.createStatement();
                //ResultSet resultado = leer.executeQuery("SELECT iddocente, Nombre, Apellidos, RFC, Direccion, EstadoCivil, Telefono FROM tabla1");
                ResultSet resultado = leer.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM tabla1");
                                 
                
                while(resultado.next()){
                    datos[0]=resultado.getString(1);
                    datos[1]=resultado.getString(2);
                    datos[2]=resultado.getString(3);
                    datos[3]=resultado.getString(4);
                    datos[4]=resultado.getString(5);
                    datos[5]=resultado.getString(6);
                    datos[6]=resultado.getString(7);
                    datos[7]=resultado.getString(8);
                    datos[8]=resultado.getString(9);
                    datos[9]=resultado.getString(10);
                    datos[10]=resultado.getString(11);
                    datos[11]=resultado.getString(12);
                    tablaDocentes.addRow(datos);
                }
              
                tablaDocentes.setModel(tablaDocente);
        } 
        
        catch (Exception e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e + " --- Error en la consulta");
                System.out.println(e);
        }
         
     
    }
```